# Question on Virtual hosts and related internet stats

Tags: dns, ip, virtualhost

as per latest Zone file (http://www.premiumdrops.com/zones.html) 
there are 230 million registered domain names.

If many of them are on virtual hosting, i.e. each one not bound to unique IP then there are much less number of IPv4 addresses in use for hosting.

I have a stat which says 33 million domains hosted on 4.5 million unique IPs.

My question is-
1. How are IPv4 addresses running out ? when total possible are order of 4000 million.

1. If you were to look IPs of each existing domain , maximum you would make 230 million DNS queries , right ?
   Then why people doing web crawling claim that DNS is their bottleneck, they can cache all of these queries locally or atleast large chunk of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of domains you found is probably only for domains in a public Top Level Domain like *.com. Thus yourdomain.com is counted as 1 domain nonetheless you have dozens of subdomains like mail.yourdomain.com blog.yourdomain.com ns.yourdomain.com etc. Because there is no public archive of subdomains run by your own nameserver there is no way to tell the true number of domains existing. In contrary to counting globally assigned domains for search engines it is necessary to access all arbitrary subdomains found.

Do you really think the Internet is all about Web/HTTP? There is much more out there. Imagine all the end users with small home routers. Each of them has one public IP address, many of them online for 24/7. Most of them will not run any web service. Many organizations such as universities or bigger companies have their own IP address ranges. Not all IPs are actually in use and only a small chunk of them is used for web. Don't forget all the remaing services like E-Mail, database, NTP, IRC, UUCP, P2P, Routing (yes, many IPs are owned by routers doing nothing else) and many more ...

Comment: the subdomains part is useful perspective, but do all subdomains have to necessarily be on same IP ? True that for subdomains there is no straightfwd way to discovery.   Yes, internet is about so many other applications and supporting infrastructure like routers etc. i didnt fully imagine the numbers earlier. :)